# Clarification on $\omega^{\omega}$-bounding of random reals

Tags: set-theory

In Jech's "Set Theory", a proof of $\omega^\omega$-bounding of random reals is given (Lemma 15.30, on page 243).
I'm having trouble making sense of it, and I hope someone can shed some light. (I am aware this is similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55832/what-is-random-real-forcing but a similar problem that I do not understand arises there; hence this new question.)

The proof (paraphrased) proceeds as follows: suppose $p \Vdash \dot{f} \in \omega^\omega$. Take $k_0 < \omega$ large enough so that the condition $q_0 \leq p$ forcing $\dot{f}(\check{0}) < \check{k}_0$ satisfies that $p \setminus q_0$ has at most measure $\frac{\mu(p)}{2^{0+2}}$ (where $\mu$) is of course Lebesgue measure. Such a $q_0 \leq p$ exists since $p$ forces that $\dot{f}$ is total.

Now proceed in the same way, replacing $0$ by $n$ above, to get a sequence $q_0,q_1,q_2,\ldots$. We can now consider the set
$$
 q = p \cap \bigcap_{n = 0}^\infty q_n
$$
which is obviously Borel. It also has positive measure (and is hence a condition in the random forcing poset): observe that in the worst case,
$$
 \mu(q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mu(p)}{2^{n+2}} = \frac{\mu(p)}{2}.
$$
Now we can define a function in the ground model as follows: let $g \in \omega^\omega$ be given by
$$
 g(n) = k \iff q \Vdash \dot{f}(\check{n}) < \check{k}
$$
which is definable by the definability of forcing.

**My question:** why is this enough? As far as I understand, there is no reason to believe that $f$ is *actually* bounded above by whatever $q$ says; after all, it is certainly the case that $p \setminus q$ has also positive measure; it could force all kinds of values on $\dot{f}$.

In Bartoszyński/Judah's text they follow a similar strategy, but argue at the end that the condition they have constructed to define $g$ has full measure; that makes more sense to me (no condition $q \leq p$ can avoid a full measure set... I think?) But why is it sufficient here that $q$ is just *some* condition giving an upper bound?

Comment: Some proofreading is needed. When you chose $q_0$, it's not clear what $\dot f<\check k$ means here (since $k$ is not mentioned earlier, nor the context of $\dot f$ being smaller than a natural number is immediately obvious); you've also missed an intersection in the displayed formula computing the measure of $p$ and the lower bound of the $q_n$s (which can be simply written as $p\cap q$, by the way); finally, you can use `*some*` instead of `$\textit{some}` to create italicised text which will also be friendlier to screen readers trying to parse MathJax inside text.

Comment: Thanks @Asaf, all corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is always the same in these arguments, which is why it is so common to see authors omit it. This is a density argument.

If for every $p$ there is a stronger condition $q$ which forces *something*, then that something must be true in the (read: any) generic extension. While the parameters may vary, the truth of some existential statement will not.

What the argument shows is that given any $p$ and $\dot f$, there is an extension, $q$ and a function $g$ such that $q\Vdash\dot f<^*\check g$. Therefore, $p\Vdash\exists g\in\check{\omega^\omega},\dot f<^* g$.

Which $g$ exactly will depend on the conditions that enter your generic filter, that much is true, but it will exist nonetheless.

Think of a similar claim, "Every finite sequence of integers appears inside a Cohen real" (if we force with $\omega^{<\omega}$ ordered by reverse inclusion, in this case). Sure, given a finite sequence, we might not know if it already appears when $p$ has reached, but given any sequence, and any condition, we can extend the condition to include that sequence. So, it must have appeared at some point when taking a generic filter and interpreting the Cohen real. Where exactly? That will, of course, depend on the choice of generic and which conditions "made it into the generic".

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. To clarify, if the set $D = \{ q \leq p \, \mid \, (\exists g \in \omega^\omega)(q \Vdash f <^* g)  \}$ is dense below $p$, then $G$ meets it; whatever $g$ witnesses this must bound $\dot{f}[G]$. But this also requires the basic fact of forcing that $p \Vdash (\exists x) \varphi$ if and only if $\{ q \leq p \, \mid \, (\exists \dot{a})(q \Vdash \varphi(\dot{a})) \}$ is dense below $p$, right?

Comment: Yes. That is the definition of $p\Vdash\exists x\varphi$.